# Scale Image in QWidget for printing

Tags: qt, qpainter, qprinter

I use the following code to print a complex widget with text and static images:

```
printer = QPrinter()
printer.setResolution(PRINTER_DPI)
painter = QPainter(printer)
painter.scale(SCALE, SCALE)
my_widget.render(painter)
painter.end()
```

Text looks nice after applying `scale()` but the pixmaps on the widget still look pixelated when printed. I tried using a higher resolution source image and setting `scaledContents` on `QLabel` but this didn't seem to help.

Any ideas how I can increase the image resolution for printing?

**Edit**: I'm still interested in an answer but in the meantime I worked around the issue by using `QSvgWidget` with an svg source image instead of `QLabel`.

Comment: I cannot see the use of `QPixmap` in your code.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I changed it just before posting from pixmap = my_widget.grab(). Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Still we need to see that in your code sample to be able to suggest?

Comment: Have you tried `printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.HighResolution)`?